# Rename add to cart to buy now

Tags: addtocart

I want to change Magento **add to cart to buy now** and also I want to redirect the page. How to made that changes??

Comment: What page do you want to redirect to?

Comment: thank you for your response.. if the product from (just ex) flipkart means that automatically redirect to that corresponding website product  @DavidManners

Answer (score 1):

So to translate the text you can do a few things.

1. Inline translations: you can set-up inline translations in the admin section then when you visit the frontend you can then translate strings and translate the button text.
2. Add a locale file to your theme: if in your theme you add a locale file you can then add any translations that you wish.
3. Update the template in your theme: if you add the template to your theme you can simply change the text shown.

I would go with the theme locale option here. Just create a file `public/app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv` then in this file translate your string.

Comment: thank you so much sir... its very helpful for me @DavidManners